# How can I translate my webpage to another language (Can't use google translator or any else)

Tags: localization, translation, html

Basically i want a translator that translates my webpage to a specific language (**word meanings are project specific**). Now for that language words and corresponding word meaning should be made manually. i mean , something like a dictionary should be there. **Because the words / texts that are need to be converted have specific meanings based on my project.** **So what is the best method / concept / approach to do this ?**

Comment: Uh... pay someone.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams bulshit

Comment: The alternative is three years of language classes. Your call.